# can we call javascript function in c# code in Asp.net MVC view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to get and pass the HTML element(a textbox) value as a query string to the Ajax.ActionLink(), is this possible? If yes, then please tell me how?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The HTMLHelper renders the a-tag before any value has been set to a textbox. If you want a kind of dynamical action you should consider creating the AJAX-link by yourself. Or you could try to insert an OnClick-javascript-function which manipulates the a-tag's href-attribute to add a MVC-value into the URL... but I'm not sure if the HTMLHelper will add the HTMLOptions before or after the AJAX-onClick-valules...